# animation frame queue vs micro task queue

Tags: html, event-loop

I guess that the microTask is processed in any steps.

And I tested these things, but I'm not sure that my assumption is right.

#### Test 1 - macroTask & microTask

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('-- macro --')
    queueMicrotask(() => console.log('** micro **'));
  });
}
```

results

```
-- macro --
** micro **
-- macro --
** micro **
```

#### Test 2 - microTask & animation frame

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    console.log('@@ animation callback @@');
    queueMicrotask(() => {
      console.log('** micro **');
    });
  });
}
```

results

```
@@ animation callback @@
** micro **
@@ animation callback @@
** micro **
@@ animation callback @@
** micro **
```

I was surprised when I first saw the results of this test. Because I thought that all tasks in the animation frame queue will be processed at once.

But, now I think that **"while processing the animation frame callback functions, check if the microTaskQueue is empty, and if there is a task inside, process it, and call the next animation frame callback (inserted by `requestAnimationFrame` function."**

Am I right, or am I missing something important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The microtask queue is visited every time the JS call stack is empty, as part of [clean after running a script](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#clean-up-after-running-script).

> 3. If the JavaScript execution context stack is now empty, perform a microtask checkpoint.

This step is entered in between all the [animation callback execution](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/imagebitmap-and-animations.html#run-the-animation-frame-callbacks), from the [invoke](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#invoke-a-callback-function) algorithm.

Note that the event-loop processing also has a few hard-coded microtask checkpoints, e.g at [step 7](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-processing-model:event-loop), but also in other callbacks execution.

Comment: Thanks Kaiido, your answer helps me a lot. I have an another question. In this [example code](https://codepen.io/_-0-_/pen/KKZpqMv) that you give me at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71454458/practical-example-where-micro-task-queue-is-useful-in-event-loop) you said **click events are generally fired from an animation frame**, but It is really hard to find about it to me. I'm reading [DOM Event Architecture](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#dom-event-architecture) and [Event Handlers](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handler-attributes), but hard

Comment: Yeah, it's more by experience running a lot of tests that I noticed this is the case. Mousemove events and other pointer events [are throttled to animated frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711515/javascript-eventlistener-pointermove-points-per-second/57719951#57719951), I think click aren't really but in most of the tests I performed the results were as if they were, (at least in Chrome and FF). But note that this doesn't mean it's part of the rAF callbacks, it's just that they wait for the "animation frame" to execute the task.

Comment: I finished a presentation about event loop. I really feel thanks to you. Have a nice day.

Comment: You're welcome. By curiosity, where was this presentation? In Seoul? I might be interested in visiting someday.

Comment: Hello Kaiido!! Sorry for late comment. this is the [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YpQTeIqjC4o) of my presentation. But, this is korean.  If you live in Seoul, I want to meet you. Would you please send me an email (rpf5573@kakao.com) ?